# Your Main Activity class com.example.eres.MainActivity is not a subclass FlutterFragmentActivity

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

I'm implementing stripe payment system in flutter application, I got error

```
PlatformException (PlatformException(flutter_stripe initialization failed, The plugin failed to initialize:
Your Main Activity class com.example.eres.MainActivity is not a subclass FlutterFragmentActivity.
Please make sure you follow all the steps detailed inside the README: https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe#android
If you continue to have trouble, follow this discussion to get some support https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/discussions/538, null, null))
```

when I run app, what can cause this error, I send another files below, error appears in line where await Stripe.instance.applySettings() is, if I delete it I will get same error again

Main.dart - main function

```
void main() async {
  HttpOverrides.global = new MyHttpOverrides();
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  Stripe.publishableKey =
      "pk_test_51LS4cRFZdZe5rLR6wpNk9gLGUxCtdm8kIaymO3CifwTxihGUdSTyRmIl0ipk4rYMfHTdNVBoBmgLbSpCP6IrCzV500wcxqU1Hv";
  await Stripe.instance.applySettings();

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

pubspec.yaml

```
name: eres
description: A new Flutter project.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.1 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  http: ^0.13.4
  loading_animation_widget: ^1.2.0+2
  provider: ^6.0.3
  flutter_switch: ^0.3.2
  json_annotation: ^4.6.0
  flutter_map: ^2.2.0
  latlong2: ^0.8.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^9.7.0
  flutter_stripe: ^2.0.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

Android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

if u have any suggestion how to fix this, please comment, thank you very much

Comment: The error is quite clear that you should subclass FlutterFragmentActivity. See https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe#android or https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/discussions/538 or comment on those thread would be quicker to get an advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In your android's MainActivity file, it should extend FlutterFragmentActivity.

> AppFolder -> Android -> app -> src -> kotlin -> com.xxx.xxx -> MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : FlutterFragmentActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) 
    {
        // Your code
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case the path was AppFolder -> Android -> app -> src -> main -> kotlin -> com.xxx.xxx -> MainActivity